# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException though array has value

Tags: arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I tried to do validation  by comparing two array values using IF condition as follows:

```
if (!bomDataArray[1].trim().equals(agileDataArray[0].trim())) {
                updateItemComments(bomDataArray[17], Constant.DESCRIPTOIN_MISMATCH);
            }
```

I am able to print the value using sysout in server. 
Code:

```
System.out.println("bomDataArray[1].trim().equals(agileDataArray[0].trim() ---> "+bomDataArray[1].trim() + "---" +(agileDataArray[0].trim()));
```

Ouput in Server:
[2018-02-26T17:22:51.158+0800] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1519636971158] [levelValue: 800] [[
  bomDataArray[1].trim().equals(agileDataArray[0].trim() ---> CAPACITOR, CERAMIC MULTILAYER, SURFACE MOUNT (CHIPS)---CAPACITOR, CERAMIC MULTILAYER, SURFACE MOUNT (CHIPS)]]

After running this, the system throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.flextronics.pdp.parser.zhuhai.ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.checkForAgileDiscrepancy(ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.java:226)
    at com.flextronics.pdp.parser.zhuhai.ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.updateBomData(ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.java:206)
    at com.flextronics.pdp.parser.zhuhai.ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.generatePdpItem(ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.java:42)
    at com.flextronics.pdp.parser.zhuhai.ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.process(ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.java:34)
    at com.flextronics.pdp.core.engine.executor.java.JavaParserExecutor.transform(JavaParserExecutor.java:43)
    at com.flextronics.pdp.core.engine.executor.PdpParserExecutor.execute(PdpParserExecutor.java:79)
    at com.flextronics.pdp.core.engine.PdpEngine.parse(PdpEngine.java:60)
    at com.flextronics.pdp.web.ux.viewmodels.documentcontrol.BomParsingViewModel.processBoms(BomParsingViewModel.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3720.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:121)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doGlobalCommandExecute(BinderImpl.java:1655)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doGlobalCommand(BinderImpl.java:1625)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.access$300(BinderImpl.java:112)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$QueueListener.onEvent(BinderImpl.java:300)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.impl.DesktopEventQueue$QueueListener.onEvent(DesktopEventQueue.java:162)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2752)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2723)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2664)
```

Please help me to understand which went wrong in this?

Comment: index out of bounds means you are trying to access an index greater that items in the array, like an array [1,2] ony has index 0 and 1. if u try to acces index 2 such an error would pop

Comment: i tired to print the values and i am able to do. (bomDataArray[1].trim().equals(agileDataArray[0].trim() ---> CAPACITOR, CERAMIC MULTILAYER, SURFACE MOUNT (CHIPS)---CAPACITOR, CERAMIC MULTILAYER, SURFACE MOUNT (CHIPS))

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown within the if-statement?

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is in ZhuhaiBomComparisonParserPlugin.java on line 226 as the stack trace says then the problem is that you're trying to access the second element of the array `bomDataArray` (with index 1) but the array has only 1 element or is empty. You need to find out why the array has less then 2 elements.

Btw, this is clearly error in your application code and has nothing to do with Payara Server your application is deployed to. You need to fix your code.